# How to disable MySQL histignore?

Tags: mysql

I'm developing password UX for an application on a new server running MySQL "8.0.17 Source distribution."

In the engine, I'm unable to use up-arrow for any query that contained the string "password," even when the field doesn't contain an actual password. (Like a flag called password_reset.) Additionally, these queries are not logged. This is a real buzzkill when I'm testing things.

I can't find any settings to adjust this, nor can I disable the "histignore" feature.

I've tried many things in the /etc/my.cnf file to no avail. I've also tried setting the MYSQL_HISTIGNORE environment variable, but it doesn't have any effect.

Edit:

Based on the comments, I've confirmed that that HISTIGNORE pattern can be extended and apparently not disabled. Therefore, I chose to change every non-password usage of "password" to "pwd" in the schema, code, and templates.

Comment: This is deliberate and legitimate MySQL behavior. "mysql ignores for logging purposes statements that match any pattern in the “ignore” list. By default, the pattern list is "*IDENTIFIED*:*PASSWORD*", to ignore statements that refer to passwords."

Comment: @SlawomirDziuba Is there a way to view and modify the pattern list?

Comment: Using -histignore you can *extend* the default pattern.

Comment: This is one of those 'features' with unintended consequences that begs for override by site admins. And yet....

Answer (score 0):

The default list is hard coded.  You can add to it at runtime, but not remove the two initial entries.
Two options for modifying the default list:

1. The *right* way is to modify the source and compile your own custom
   version of the client with the list containing anything you want
   (IE: empty).
2. If that's too much effort / not practical for your situation, and if
   bbe is available to you, you can run something like the following to
   replace the default list with one that is less likely to cause you
   problems.  This will give you a modified mysql client binary you can
   run (don't forget to chmod +x it) in /tmp/mysql.histignore_disabled

```
bbe -e 's/*IDENTIFIED*:*PASSWORD*/*xxENTIFIED*:*xxSSWORD*/' `which mysql` > /tmp/mysql.histignore_disabled
```